# Javascript file with JS object served by Spring

Tags: spring-mvc

I need to load a javascript file generated server-side using Spring.
Currently, I'm doing this:

In the html page:

```
<script src="<spring:url value="/dyn/user.js"/>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user.js", produces="application/javascript")
public String userJsp(Model model) {
   User user = getUser();
   model.addAttribute("name", user.getFirstName());
   model.addAttribute("id", user.getId());
   return "js/user.jsp";
}
```

And this is the user.jsp file:

```
window.User = {
    "id": ${id},
    "name": "${name}"
};
```

Anyway, I need more data from the User object. I want Spring to do the work for me. In the end, I want to have something like:

```
window.User = <json object generated by Spring like when you use @ResponseBody in the controller>
```

Which is the better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If there are only a few more data objects to add, then I'd keep adding new model attributes. But if there are a lot more (more than 5), then you could try using a `Map`:

```
Map<String, Object> jsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
// populate Map here
model.addAttribute("jsMap", jsMap);
```

then in your jsp:

```
window.User = {
    <c:forEach items="${jsMap}" var="entry" varStatus="status">
        "${entry.key}": "${entry.value}"${not status.last ? ',' : ''}
    </c:forEach>
};
```

You might want to add extra type checking so numeric values are not enclosed in quotes, etc (which is why I'd suggest your original approach initially).

Answer (score 0):

The creation of JS object could also be done automatically, using Jackson inside the JSP page:

```
<%@page import="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper"%>
<%@page import="com.bla.woof.User "%>

<%
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
User user = (User)request.getAttribute("user");
%>

window.User = <%= mapper.writeValueAsString(user) %>;
```

The result is something like:

```
{id: 2, username: "anto", firstName: "Antonio", lastName: "Tancredi", profile: Object}
```

As you can see, also the 'profile' member as been converted to a JS object (that's what I wanted), so you need to be sure to convert only what you really need. The Jackson library has some annotations that could help in this task.

Keep attention when you try to convert a lazy Hibernate object. Jackson will try to autodetect the object properties, and will find also the members of the Hibernate lazy proxy.
You can find some detail here:

[Strange Jackson exception being thrown when serializing Hibernate object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362104/strange-jackson-exception-being-thrown-when-serializing-hibernate-object)

For instance, my Profile class is lazy inside the User object. I needed to add this annotation:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Profile implements Serializable {
:
}
```

to tell Jackson to ignore those two members.