# No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.Javassist?

Tags: json, spring, hibernate

I am working on `SpringMVC`, `Hibernate` & `JSON` but I am getting this error.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Could not write JSON: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )
```

Please check my Entity below

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="USERS")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    private Integer userId;

    @Column(name="USER_FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="USER_LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;


    @Column(name="USER_MIDDLE_NAME")
    private String middleName;

    @Column(name="USER_EMAIL_ID")
    private String emailId;

    @Column(name="USER_PHONE_NO")
    private Integer phoneNo;

    @Column(name="USER_PASSWORD")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="USER_CONF_PASSWORD")
    private String  confPassword;

    @Transient
    private String token;

    @Column(name="USER_CREATED_ON")
    private Date createdOn;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLES", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID") })
    private List<ActifioRoles> userRole = new ArrayList<ActifioRoles>();


    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="userDetails")
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<com.actifio.domain.Address> userAddress = new ArrayList<com.actifio.domain.Address>();

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Tenant tenantDetails;


    public Integer getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getEmailId() {
        return emailId;
    }
    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getConfPassword() {
        return confPassword;
    }
    public void setConfPassword(String confPassword) {
        this.confPassword = confPassword;
    }
    public Date getCreatedOn() {
        return createdOn;
    }
    public void setCreatedOn(Date createdOn) {
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
    }

    public List<ActifioRoles> getUserRole() {
        return userRole;
    }

    public void setUserRole(List<ActifioRoles> userRole) {
        this.userRole = userRole;
    }
    public String getMiddleName() {
        return middleName;
    }
    public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
        this.middleName = middleName;
    }
    public Integer getPhoneNo() {
        return phoneNo;
    }
    public void setPhoneNo(Integer phoneNo) {
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
    }

    public List<com.actifio.domain.Address> getUserAddress() {
        return userAddress;
    }
    public void setUserAddress(List<com.actifio.domain.Address> userAddress) {
        this.userAddress = userAddress;
    }
    public Tenant getTenantDetails() {
        return tenantDetails;
    }
    public void setTenantDetails(Tenant tenantDetails) {
        this.tenantDetails = tenantDetails;
    }
    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }
    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    }
```

How can I Solve this?

Comment: Please show the stacktrace and the code where the exception occurs

Comment: Without having any knowledge of what your code is trying to do, it's a little difficult to debug, but you'll probably want to check out https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate since you are using Jackson and Hibernate

Comment: Are you trying to make a JSON from this class? In this case, the JSON serializer tries to write all the properties, also the HashSet of your many-to-many relationships; this makes a lazy initializer exception

Comment: same question can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362104/strange-jackson-exception-being-thrown-when-serializing-hibernate-object

Comment: The most recent version of hibernate seems to be using ByteBuddy instead of java assist. The cause and solution are still the same. Exception:
Type definition error: [simple type, class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)

Answer (score 224, accepted):

I had a similar problem with lazy loading via the hibernate proxy object. Got around it by annotating the class having lazy loaded private properties with:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
```

I assume you can add the properties on your proxy object that breaks the JSON serialization to that annotation.

The problem is that entities are loaded lazily and serialization happens before they get loaded fully.

```
Hibernate.initialize(<your getter method>);
```

Comment: It worked for me too... Is there any explanation to this weird behavior?

Comment: @ankur-singhal where to call Hibernate.initialize(<your getter method>); ?

Comment: @KaizarLaxmidhar depends in which flow you are getting exception, can be done just before serialization, persisting, re-directing to view etc.

Comment: @ankur-singhal you should emphasize that this annotation is needed on the nested class and NOT the calling class.

Comment: Yahooo... it worked. I tried few times and worked. I tried few ways and BoooM. Worked.

Comment: Thanks worked for me too. You need to add this annotation to entities which access other entities having lazy loaded beans.

Comment: You should have added some explanation. Actually sometimes Hibernate returns not the actual object but some proxy object that has all the fields as null and this field hibernateLazyInitializer not null. I guess other fields will get their correct values if requested but this field obviously cannot be serialized. Hence the need for this annotation.

Comment: I think this is not a right solution for the issue. When we serialize, we expect either complete subobject, or at least primary key of the sub-object to  be returned back in the result. Adding these annotations will just suppress the error, but will not provide you desired results.

Comment: This is not working when I am wrapping things in DTO object having same object annotated with `@JsonIgnoreProperties`. Any quick help?

Comment: This doesn't works in my case. Should I be removing @IgnoreJson ?

Answer (score 92):

Just to add this in, I ran into this same issue, but the supplied answers did not work. I fixed it by taking the exception's suggestion and adding to the application.properties file...

```
spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false
```

I'm using Spring Boot v1.3 with Hibernate 4.3

It now serializes the entire object and nested objects.

**EDIT: 2018**

Since this still gets comments I'll clarify here. This *absolutely* only hides the error. The performance implications are there. At the time, I needed something to deliver and work on it later (which I did via not using spring anymore). So yes, listen to someone else if you really want to solve the issue. If you just want it gone for now go ahead and use this answer. It's a terrible idea, but heck, might work for you. For the record, never had a crash or issue again after this. But it is probably the source of what ended up being a SQL performance nightmare.

Comment: Solves the problem but json will contain two extra unneeded properties `"handler":{},"hibernateLazyInitializer":{}`

Comment: great! fixed here too, this is the answer

Comment: @prettyvoid Why that extra properties are exists?

Comment: @RobertMoon If you want to get rid of them you can annotate your entity with `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})`

Comment: @prettyvoid Thanks.
I found another solution is change LAZY to EAGER.
Is it affect on a performance?

Comment: This also solved my issue. The annotation @JsonIgnore... did not solve my issue.

Comment: If you're running into issues with the supplied answer make sure you're adding the json ignore annotation on the nested class.

Comment: This is not the solution. This just hides the problem. Hibernate covers your property with "lazy proxy initializer" class, which loads the property when accessed for the first time. Jackson tries to serialize this class, instead of the real property, that's why it crashes with this message.

Answer (score 79):

As it is correctly suggested in previous answers, lazy loading means that when you fetch your object from the database, the nested objects are not fetched (and may be fetched later when required).

Now Jackson tries to serialize the nested object (== make JSON out of it), but fails as it finds JavassistLazyInitializer instead of normal object. This is the error you see. Now, how to solve it?

As [suggested by CP510](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35497279) earlier, one option is to suppress the error by this line of configuration:

```
spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false
```

But this is **dealing with the symptoms, not the cause**. To solve it elegantly, you need to decide whether you need this object in JSON or not?

1. Should you need the object in JSON, remove the `FetchType.LAZY` option from the field that causes it (it might also be a field in some nested object, not only in the root entity you are fetching).
2. If you do not need the object in JSON, annotate the getter of this field (or the field itself, if you do not need to accept incoming values either) with `@JsonIgnore`, for example:

   ```java
   // this field will not be serialized to/from JSON
   @JsonIgnore
   private NestedType secret;
   ```

Should you have more complex needs (e.g. different rules for different REST controllers using the same entity), you can use jackson [views](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews) or [filtering](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureJsonFilter) or for very simple use case, fetch nested objects separately.

Comment: This is the best answer.  Address the root of the problem, don't just mask the symptoms for the next programmer to have to deal with.

Comment: You are my hero.

Comment: thank you very much for explaining the reason behind the error and providing two solutions that make sense

Comment: Thanks for this, however I see springfox-swagger still gives me error `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Answer (score 24):

You could use the add-on module for Jackson which handles Hibernate lazy-loading.

More info on https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate wich support hibernate 3 and 4 separately.

Comment: This should be really the correct answer. All the other answers are hidding the issue rather than solving it.

Comment: But how to use this module? is there any guide for it?

Comment: Ways to configure jackson-datatype-hibernate:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/33727017

Answer (score 14):

I think that the problem is the way that you retrieve the entity.

Maybe you are doing something like this:

```
Person p = (Person) session.load(Person.class, new Integer(id));
```

Try using the method `get` instead of `load`

```
Person p = (Person) session.get(Person.class, new Integer(id));
```

The problem is that with load method you get just a proxy but not the real object. The proxy object doesn't have the properties already loaded so when the serialization happens there are no properties to be serialized. With the get method you actually get the real object, this object could in fact be serialized.

Comment: A very similar error happened to me when I used getOne instead of findOne.  In my case, my interface repository was extending JpaRepository.  findOne worked well without any Json annotations or changes in application.properties

Comment: Like James Freitas, I also found that the getOne led to the issue, and using instead, for example, findById -solved the issue without need to use the annotation or the above given line in the application properties

Comment: My work mate clarified me and told that: "The basic difference is that getOne is lazy loaded and findOne is not" - meaning obviously that the former does not actually get data rows from the db but just creates references. The latter, instead gets rows actually, which is the case which often is desired

Comment: @JamesFreitas YES! Thank you! And thank you Carlos for leading James to this nice conclusion!

Answer (score 11):

it works for me

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer","handler"})
```

e.g.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer","handler"})
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private Date created;

}
```

Answer (score 7):

There are two ways to fix the problem.

**Way 1**:

Add 
`spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false` into **application.properties**

**Way 2**:

Use `join fetch` in JPQL query to retrieve parent object data, see below:

```
@Query(value = "select child from Child child join fetch child.parent Parent ",
           countQuery = "select count(*) from Child child join child.parent parent ")
public Page<Parent> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Thank's! The first solution it's great!

Comment: Way 1. Great. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Add this Annotation to Entity Class (Model) that works for me
this cause lazy loading via the hibernate proxy object.

> @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})

Answer (score 2):

This Exception

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException

getting because, I hope so, your are sending response output as Serializable object. 
This is problem occurring in  spring. To over come this issue, send POJO object as response output.

Example :

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="user_details")
    public class User implements Serializable{

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="id")
        private Integer id;

        @Column(name="user_name")
        private String userName;

        @Column(name="email_id")
        private String emailId;

        @Column(name="phone_no")
        private String phone;

//setter and getters
```

POJO class:

```
public class UserVO {

    private int Id;
    private String userName;
    private String emailId;
    private String phone;
    private Integer active;

//setter and getters
```

In controller convert the serilizable object fields to POJO class fields and return pojo class as output.

```
         User u= userService.getdetials(); // get data from database

        UserVO userVo= new UserVO();  // created pojo class object

        userVo.setId(u.getId());
        userVo.setEmailId(u.getEmailId());
        userVo.setActive(u.getActive());
        userVo.setPhone(u.getPhone());
        userVo.setUserName(u.getUserName());
       retunr userVo;  //finally send pojo object as output.
```

Comment: Yes I am doing the same, but even doing the same I am getting the same error, because I am sending objects associated data which is nothing but setting Entity classes

Answer (score 2):

In the Hibernate 5.2 and above, you able to remove the hibernate proxy as below, it will give you the actual object so you can serialize it properly:

```
Object unproxiedEntity = Hibernate.unproxy( proxy );
```

Comment: it will automatically call `Hibernate.initialize` beforehand as well.

Comment: @Tim, it should be added before the json serialization. The issue happen because there is hibernate proxy object found during serialization, so once removed it, serialization will be fine. If you are using spring controller, then you have to do it before the controller end.

Answer (score 2):

For Hibernate you can use the [jackson-datatype-hibernate](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate) project to accommodate JSON serialization/deserialization with lazy-loaded objects.

For example,

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.hibernate5.Hibernate5Module;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class JacksonDatatypeHibernate5Configuration {

    // Register Jackson Hibernate5 Module to handle JSON serialization of lazy-loaded entities
    // Any beans of type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module are automatically
    // registered with the auto-configured Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder
    // https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper
    @Bean
    public Module hibernate5Module() {
        Hibernate5Module hibernate5Module = new Hibernate5Module();
        hibernate5Module.enable( Hibernate5Module.Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING );
        hibernate5Module.disable( Hibernate5Module.Feature.USE_TRANSIENT_ANNOTATION );
        return hibernate5Module;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I used this then I get `can't parse JSON.  Raw result:`. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

I've the same problem right now.
check if you fix fetch in lazy with a @jsonIQgnore

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="teachers")
@JsonIgnoreProperties("course")
Teacher teach;
```

Just delete the "(fetch=...)" or the annotation "@jsonIgnore" and it will work

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="teachers")
@JsonIgnoreProperties("course")
Teacher teach;
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is inspired from the below solution by @marco. I have also updated his answer with these datails.

The problem here is about lazy loading of the sub-objects, where Jackson only finds hibernate proxies, instead of full blown objects.

So we are left with two options - Suppress the exception, like done above in most voted answer here, or make sure that the LazyLoad objects are loaded.

If you choose to go with latter option, solution would be to use [jackson-datatype](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate) library, and configure the library to initialize lazy-load dependencies prior to the serialization.

I added a new config class to do that.

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
@Primary
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonMessageConverter(){
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Hibernate5Module module = new Hibernate5Module();
    module.enable(Hibernate5Module.Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING);
    mapper.registerModule(module);
    messageConverter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
    return messageConverter;
}
```

}

`@Primary` makes sure that no other Jackson config is used for initializing any other beans. `@Bean` is as usual. `module.enable(Hibernate5Module.Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING);` is to enable Lazy loading of the dependencies.

Caution - Please watch for its performance impact. sometimes EAGER fetch helps, but even if you make it eager, you are still going to need this code, because proxy objects still exist for all other Mappings except `@OneToOne`

PS : As a general comment, I would discourage the practice of sending whole data object back in the Json response, One should be using Dto's for this communication, and use some mapper like mapstruct to map them. This saves you from accidental security loopholes, as well as above exception.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could configure mapper as :

// custom configuration for lazy loading

```
public static class HibernateLazyInitializerSerializer extends JsonSerializer<JavassistLazyInitializer> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(JavassistLazyInitializer initializer, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
            SerializerProvider serializerProvider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jsonGenerator.writeNull();
    }
}
```

and configure mapper:

```
    mapper = new JacksonMapper();
    SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule(
            "SimpleModule", new Version(1,0,0,null)
    );
    simpleModule.addSerializer(
            JavassistLazyInitializer.class,
            new HibernateLazyInitializerSerializer()
    );
    mapper.registerModule(simpleModule);
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be your Hibernate entity relationship causing the issue...simply stop lazy loading of that related entity...for example...I resolved below by setting lazy="false" for customerType.

```
<class name="Customer" table="CUSTOMER">
        <id name="custId" type="long">
            <column name="CUSTID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NAME" />
        </property>
        <property name="phone" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="PHONE" />
        </property>
        <property name="pan" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="PAN" />
        </property>

        <many-to-one name="customerType" not-null="true" lazy="false"></many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: please inform in your post that it can be very danger solution in real life application.

Answer (score 0):

I changed (in Annotation model class)

> fetch = FetchType.LAZY

to

> fetch = FetchType.EAGER

and worked in pretty way...

Love it.

Comment: While this does solve the problem it is very dangerous. Changing the `fetch` strategy on a model has several consequences in performance. With this change, you are bringing much more data from the database. It may be a valid solution, but first a performance study is needed.

Comment: If you know you're model, and wont have many entities related, you can spend a little bit of mem and perfomance to get a full entity. but is good to know that is always best you use LAZY fetch

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with Jackson. To prevent this, instruct Jackson not to serialize nested relationship or nested class.

Look at the following example. **Address** class mapped to **City**, **State**, and **Country** classes and the State itself is pointing to Country and Country pointing to Region. When your get address values through Spring boot REST API you will get the above error. To prevent it, just serialize mapped class ( which reflects level one JSON) and ignore nested relationships with        `@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"state"})`,`@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"country"})` and
`@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"region"})`

This will prevent Lazyload exception along with the above error. Use the below code as an example and change your model classes.

**Address.java**

```
@Entity
public class Address extends AbstractAuditingEntity
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4203344613880544060L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "street_name")
    private String streetName;

    @Column(name = "apartment")
    private String apartment;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"state"})
    private City city;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "state_id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"country"})
    private State state;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"region"})
    private Country country;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "region_id")
    private Region region;

    @Column(name = "zip_code")
    private String zipCode;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_type_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private AddressType addressType;

}
```

**City.java**

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "city")
@Cache(region = "cityCache",usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@Data
public class City extends AbstractAuditingEntity
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8825045541258851493L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    //@Length(max = 100,min = 2)
    private String name;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "state_id")
    private State state;
}
```

**State.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "state")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class State extends AbstractAuditingEntity
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5553856435782266275L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "name")
    @Length(max = 200, min = 2)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id")
    private Country country;

}
```

**Country.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "country")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Country extends AbstractAuditingEntity
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6396100319470393108L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    @Length(max = 200, min = 2)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "code")
    @Length(max = 3, min = 2)
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "iso_code")
    @Length(max = 3, min = 2)
    private String isoCode;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "region_id")
    private Region region;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer","handler"})

it works for me

Answer (score -6):

Try

`implements interface Serializable`