# JPA @OneToMany get latest record by date from Join

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Getting stuck trying to fetch the latest record from a **Join**
I have the following classes

Author

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "author")
    public class Author {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @OrderBy("id Desc")
    private List<Book> books;
    public int getId() {
       return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
       this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
       return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
    }
    public List<Book> getBooks() {
       return books;
    }
    public void setBooks(List<Book> books) {
       this.books = books;
     }
    }
```

Book

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "book")
    public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "author_id")
    private Integer authorId;
    @Column(name = "date_published")
    private Date datePublished;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
       this.id = id;
    }
    public Integer getAuthorId() {
       return authorId;
    }
    public void setAuthorId(Integer authorId) {
       this.authorId = authorId;
    }
    public Date getDatePublished() {
       return datePublished;
    }
    public void setDatePublished(Date datePublished) {
       this.datePublished = datePublished;
     }
    }
```

Repository

```
    @Repository
    public interface AuthorRepository extends 
    JpaRepository<Author, Long> {

         public Page<Author> findALL(int id, Pageable pageable);

    }
```

Current results

```
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "James",
      "books":[
      {
         "id": 1,
         "name": "book1",
         "datePublished": '12/12/2012'

      },
      {
         "id": 1,
         "name": "book2",
         "datePublished": '01/02/2013'
      }]
    },

    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Tim",
      "books":[
      {
         "id": 5,
         "name": "book5",
         "datePublished": '12/12/2014'

      },{
          "id": 6,
          "name": "book6",
          "datePublished": '01/02/2015'

       }]
    }
```

Expected Result

```
    {
       "id": 1,
       "name": "James",
       "books":[
       {
         "id": 1,
         "name": "book2",
         "datePublished": '01/02/2013'
       }]
   },
   {
     "id": 2,
     "name": "Tim",
     "books":[
     {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "book6",
        "datePublished": '01/02/2015'

     }]
   }
```

From this a list of **Authors** are being returned with all their respective books.

Question is how can JPA assist me to pick only the latest book from the collection based on date published.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on your question,  "how can JPA assist me to pick only the latest book from the collection based on date published."?

Comment: Just added current and expected results. Hope that makes it a bit clear. Probably if its possible to do a max date on the collection of books per author

Comment: So, basically, you are trying to get the latest book (single book) from list of books for each users?

Comment: Yes. Find all authors with their latest book. Remember the repository will have different calls based on need. Just need one to return the latest book

Comment: One question, why you have JoinColumn in your Author Entity having OneToMany relationship with Book Entity? You will run into issues. The JoinColumn is for owning side which in this case would be Books since A Author can have multiple books.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are using hibernate you can achieve this using `@JoinFormula` to map the latest record by date. Something like:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinFormula("(" +
    "SELECT b.id " +
    "FROM book b " +
    "WHERE b.author_id = id " +
    "ORDER BY b.date_published DESC " +
    "LIMIT 1" +
")")
private Book latestBook;
```

Comment: Thanks works for me with reference to this site https://vladmihalcea.com/2017/02/16/how-to-map-the-latest-child-of-a-parent-entity-using-hibernate-joinformula/

Comment: Had following error "No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.Javassist"  due to Lazy loading but was assisted with the following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24994440/no-serializer-found-for-class-org-hibernate-proxy-pojo-javassist-javassist. I wonder what are its effects?

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem. The other solution is with `@Where` annotation:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "author_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@Where(clause = "date_published = (SELECT MAX(book.date_published) " +
                                   "FROM book" +
                                   "where author_id = book.author_id)")
@OrderBy("datePublished Desc")
private List<Book> books;
```

My post on stack: [Get applications with their latest status only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63231485/find-lastest-status-date-for-each-application-using-where-clausule-instead-of-gr)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get last book for each author , you can add transient field to get it :

```
@Entity
    @Table(name = "author")
    public class Author {
    .......
    @Transient 
    private Book lastBook;

   @PostLoad
   private void setLastBook() {
  if(books==null || books,isEmpty())
     this.lastBook=null;
  }else{
    this.lastBook=books.get(0);
  }
}
```

or make it one to one and save it in db by same method annotated with @PostPersist and @PostUpdate. it will save in db automatically last book

Answer (score 0):

the answer by @Seldo97 is correct, but he missed the space between "book" and "where" in the Select query, which will throw an error.

so basically it should be

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "author_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@Where(clause = "date_published = (SELECT MAX(book.date_published) " +
                                   "FROM book" +
                                   " where author_id = book.author_id)")
@OrderBy("datePublished Desc")
private List<Book> books;
```

- author_id -> basically refers to foreign key column name in the child.
  entity
- date_published -> this refers to the column by which we want to
  sort(in this case the date column name).

so, the above query will take the record with the latest date and put it in the list object:

```
List<book> book;
```