# Get only the latest status by MAX function for each Application using WHERE clausule instead of ORDER BY

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I would like to obtain the same result of query using `WHERE` instead of `GROUP BY`. I have applications and each application has statuses with date. I need to return applications with their latest status date.
My query with `ORDER BY`: (the result is correct)

```
select a.guid, MAX(s.request_time) as last_request_time 
from public.applications_status s inner join public.applications a on a.guid = s.guid_application
group by a.guid ;
```

result:

```
guid                                |last_request_time  |
------------------------------------|-------------------|
330d32d5-2496-4cce-9d11-29e59333766a|2020-07-22 13:06:25|
5b46cda9-b954-4d8b-82cf-f1d83f77b175|2020-07-22 13:07:25|
34071189-ab3d-47ff-9ee1-aca6fa806bc9|2020-08-03 10:45:15|
a8961058-a6ee-4d71-b325-9aca83b22237|2020-08-03 10:45:39|
ff98695f-e1a8-439e-8a6c-7991348b6cd7|2020-07-29 14:38:18|
```

I try this but it return me only the one application with latest status date:

```
select a.guid, s.request_time 
from public.applications_status s inner join public.applications a on a.guid = s.guid_application
where request_time = (select MAX(applications_status.request_time) from applications_status );
```

result:

```
guid                                |request_time       |
------------------------------------|-------------------|
a8961058-a6ee-4d71-b325-9aca83b22237|2020-08-03 10:45:39|
```

**Applications table**

```
CREATE TABLE public.applications (
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    guid varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    "name" varchar(60) NOT NULL,
    latest_status_date timestamp NULL,
    latest_status bool NOT NULL,
    id_production bigserial NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT applications_guid_key UNIQUE (guid),
    CONSTRAINT applications_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT uk_gtuqgycxk8ulkir3io2p49yn1 UNIQUE (guid),
    CONSTRAINT fkaid_prod FOREIGN KEY (id_production) REFERENCES productions(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

**Applications_status table**

```
CREATE TABLE public.applications_status (
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    status bool NOT NULL,
    guid_application varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    log varchar(200) NULL,
    request_time timestamp NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT status_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fkaguid_application FOREIGN KEY (guid_application) REFERENCES applications(guid) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Why I need this way? I try to return Applications with their latest status in Spring Boot using `@Where` annotation in `@OneToMany` relation in `Entity`.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "application", fetch = LAZY)
@JsonManagedReference
@Where(clause = "request_time = (SELECT MAX(applications_status.request_time) FROM applications_status )")
@OrderBy("requestTime DESC")
private List<ApplicationStatus> applicationStatuses;
```

I also try to use `@BatchSize(size = 1)` but it doesn't work.

Comment: `request_time = (select MAX(applications_status.request_time) from applications_status` not good because `time` is not unique kind of data

Comment: @T.S. thats why I'm looking for correct solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through trial and error, I found a solution:

SQL query:

```
select a.guid, s.request_time 
from public.applications_status s inner join public.applications a on a.guid = s.guid_application
where request_time = (select MAX(applications_status.request_time) 
                        from applications_status 
                        where applications_status.guid_application = s.guid_application );
```

Spring-Boot:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "application", fetch = LAZY)
@JsonManagedReference
@Where(clause = "request_time = (SELECT MAX(applications_status.request_time) FROM applications_status where guid_application = applications_status.guid_application )")
@OrderBy("requestTime DESC")
private List<ApplicationStatus> applicationStatuses;
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is tagged both "sql" and "postgres", so this is a Postgres solution.

Use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (a.guid) a.*, s.*
from public.applications_status s inner join
     public.applications a
     on a.guid = s.guid_application
order by a.guid, s.request_time desc;
```

`distinct on` is a very handy Postgres extension that returns one row (the "first" row) for each group in the parentheses.  The particular row is based on the `order by`.

Comment: Answer is correct for query directly in database but I need to use it in `@Where` in Spring Boot.

Comment: @Seldo97 . . . I clarified that the answer is only for the database.