# No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer

Tags: java, hibernate, jackson

This question seems to be the same as this [No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.Javassist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24994440/no-serializer-found-for-class-org-hibernate-proxy-pojo-javassist-javassist). But there are some differences. The author of that question has lazy relationships. Instead, my entity is so simple:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Length(min = 5, max = 50, message = "error.firstName.length")
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Length(min = 5, max = 50, message = "error.lastName.length")
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    public User(Long id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public User(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this(null, firstName, lastName);
    }

    public User() {}

    // getters & setters

}
```

but I still get this error:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No
>   serializer found for class
>   org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no
>   properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception,
>   disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference
>   chain:
>   ua.savenkodenys.user_management.persistence.entity.User_$$_jvst11c_0["handler"]) (in the error description)

I also want to know what is this - (through reference chain: **ua.savenkodenys.user_management.persistence.entity.User_$$_jvst11c_0["handler"]**) (in the error description).

```
ua.savenkodenys.user_management.persistence.entity - these are my packages
```

Comment: Just use DTO and mapstruct

Comment: @NickSavenia I'm using Spring Data Jpa.

Comment: convert entity to dto object using mapstruct and return dto object, not entity, from controller

Comment: @NickSavenia please, can you give an example?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application

Answer (score 1):

[jackson-datatype-hibernate](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate) accommodates JSON serialization/deserialization with lazy-loaded objects.

With lazy-loading, a proxy object stands in for your object until your object can be retrieved from the database, so that's what the reference chain is referring to.

This question may be a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55719356/9260161), so try implementing the configuration class mentioned there first.

Alternatively, you could try adding the following annotation to your User entity, though this merely masks the problem rather than solving it.

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
```