# JPA returning a nested object after creation - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have my main object:

```
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@Table(name = MAIN_OBJ)
public class MainObj {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "MAIN_OBJ_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer manObjId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "SUB_OBJ_ID", referencedColumnName = "SUB_OBJ_ID", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private SubObj subObj;

}
```

and it's sub object:

```
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@Table(name = SUB_OBJ)
public class SubObj {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "SUB_OBJ_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer subObjId;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private String name;

}
```

When I do a creation:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public MainObj create(MainObj mainObj) {
    MainObj createdMainObj = mainObjRepository.save(mainObj);
    return createdMainObj;
}
```

It saves properly but when I return it to the user (back through the controller) I get a 500 back. After debugging I can see that all the fields in the subObj are null.

But it does actually create the mainObj and put it into the db, it just fails to serialize it and return.

If I trace it enough I see:

> No serializer found for class
>   org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer

Not really sure what I need to add so I can return the fully created object with it's foreign key reference to the subObj back to the user.

I tried Hibernate.initialize() like a lot of posts said but no luck.

If it wasn't clear it gives me one of these back:

[image]

Full stack trace (some details removed):

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException:
>   Could not write JSON: No serializer found for class
>   org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no
>   properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception,
>   disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS); nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer
>   found for class
>   org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no
>   properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception,
>   disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference
>   chain:
>   com.path.to.MainObj["subObj"]-com.path.to.SubObj_$$_jvsta14_f["handler"])

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.Javassist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24994440/no-serializer-found-for-class-org-hibernate-proxy-pojo-javassist-javassist)

Comment: Can you change your @ManyToOne to something like @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER), please read about it to understand the performance implications as well.

Comment: @AdilKhalil `fetch = EAGER` *is* the default for `@ManyToOne`

Comment: That's the main thing I don't get, why is LazyInitializer involved at all when it's an EAGER load?

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is NOT return entity directly in controller (because it may cause stack over flow exception). The entity should convert to DTO (data transfer object) and return DTO.

If you still want to use entity, you should use eager instead of lazy for all references (includes reference object inside reference object);

Comment: ManyToOne is eager by default. And we are converting it into a DTO. But it doesn't help as the sub objects stays in that weird state where if you open it in the debugger it says everything is null and has a 'handler' on it. If you open the handler you can find the full definition for the object under that.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this ?
Add this annotation to SubObj Class

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="SUB_OBJ_ID")
```

Comment: What file would you put that on?

Comment: Already mentioned @canpan14 in my comment : You add this annotation above SubObj Class(model)

Comment: Oh I'm blind! Thanks!

Comment: 415 Unsupported Media Type.  Invalid Object Id definition for path.to.SubObj: can not find property with name 'SUB_OBJ_ID'

Comment: I tried subObjId to match the variable name and it went back to the original 500 error.