# Hibernate returns an object not null, but that is strangely lazy itself : JavassistLazyInitializer

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-entitymanager, criteriaquery

The problem is not always reproducible, it's when getting my object from the database using CriteriaBuilder.

Code :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = MyEntityObject.TABLE_NAME)
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@BatchSize(size = 50)
public class MyEntityObject extends AbstractCodeEntity implements Comparable<MyEntityObject> {
```

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<MyEntityObject> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(MyEntityObject.class);

Root<MyEntityObject> root = criteriaQuery.from(MyEntityObject.class);

Predicate condition = builder.equal(root.get(MyEntityObject.code), code);
boolean distinct = FetchBuilder.buildFetchs(root, fetchsOperations);
criteriaQuery.distinct(distinct).where(condition);

TypedQuery<MyEntityObject> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

return query.getSingleResult();
```

Of course MyEntityObject has attributes as lazy and others as eager

When I'm debugging, the returned object contains a handler = {JavassistLazyInitializer@19574} + objet attributes which are null.

I've tried to find out if hibernate go look for it on the database => he did

Then if the object exists on 1st cach => it doesn't

Anyone have an idea ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, that behavior is perfectly normal when getting an Entity that has relationships with `FetchType.LAZY`. Are you aware of Hibernate/JPA Lazy and Eager fetching/loading and what it does? See: [Difference between FetchType LAZY and EAGER in Java Persistence API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990799/difference-between-fetchtype-lazy-and-eager-in-java-persistence-api)

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Yes, I'm aware of that, but here the object I'm looking to get itsef looks lazy, I don't really understand this behaviour. (I added the code above)

Comment: Oh, so the whole root `MyEntityObject` that you select is returned as a Hibernate Lazy-Load Proxy object instead of an actual object? If that is the case I'm not able to explain that behavior either.

Comment: Did you give it a try without the CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE?

Comment: @Thomas it's not that easy to reproduce. Can you explain how does it impact?

Comment: It's just a guess. What is actually the problem with JavassistLazyInitializer? Do you get an exception when accessing the fields?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, good question, the object becomes null later on the code

Comment: It becomes null as a result of serializing the object which is considered empty

Answer (score 0):

Two notes from my side - not sure if this fully covers your issues:

- Check out [No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.Javassist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24994440/no-serializer-found-for-class-org-hibernate-proxy-pojo-javassist-javassist) if some of the solutions can be applied to your case
- What are you serializing the entity for? Maybe you can find a way to copy the relevant values into another object, and don't serialize the entity