# Spring boot response REST service error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

My project is at https://github.com/murillocg/SpringBootTest

When I acess any URI, like localhost/video, get follow response:

```
{"_links":{"search":{
        "href":"http://localhost:8080/video/search"
    }
},
"_embedded":{
"videos":[{"id":1,
    "name":"Jogo da Imitacao",
    "url":"www.globo.com",
    "duration":123,
    "persistentEntity":{
    "idProperty":
        {"name":"id",
         "rawType":"long",
         "field":{
            "name":"id",
            "type":"long",
            "modifiers":2,
            "annotations":[{},{}],
            "synthetic":false,
            "declaredAnnotations":[{},{}],
            "declaringClass":"hello.repository.Video",
            "enumConstant":false,
            "genericType":"long",
            "accessible":true},
            "association":false,
            "owner":{
                "idProperty":{
                    "name":"id",
                    "rawType":"long",
                    "field":{
                        "name":"id",
                        "type":"long",
                        "modifiers":2,
                        "annotations":[{},{}],
                        "synthetic":false,
                        "declaredAnnotations":[{},{}],
                        "declaringClass":"hello.repository.Video",
                        "enumConstant":false,
                        "genericType":"long",
                        "accessible":true
                    },
                    "association":false,
                    "owner":{
                        "idProperty":{
                            "name":"id",
                            "rawType":"long",
                            "field":{
                                "name":"id",
                                "type":"long",
                                "modifiers":2,
                                "annotations":[{},{}],
                                "synthetic":false,
                                "declaredAnnotations":[{},{}],
                                "declaringClass":"hello.repository.Video",
                                "enumConstant":false,
                                "genericType":"long",
                                "accessible":true
                            },
                                "association":false,
                                "owner":{
                                    "idProperty":{
                                        "name":"id",
                                        "rawType":"long",
                                        "field":{
                                            "name":"id",
                                            "type":"long",
                                            "modifiers":2,
                                            "annotations":[{},{}],
                                            "synthetic":false,
                                            "declaredAnnotations":[{},{}],
                                            "declaringClass":"hello.repository.Video",
                                            "enumConstant":false,
                                            "genericType":"long",
                                            "accessible":true
                                        },
                                        "association":false,
                                        "owner":{
                                            "idProperty":{
                                                "name":"id",
                                                "rawType":"long",
                                                "field":{
                                                    "name":"id",
                                                    "type":"long",
                                                    "modifiers":2,
                                                    "annotations":[{},{}],
                                                    "synthetic":false,
                                                    "declaredAnnotations":[{},{}],
                                                    "declaringClass":"hello.repository.Video",
                                                    "enumConstant":false,
                                                    "genericType":"long",
                                                    "accessible":true
                                                },
                                                "association":false,
                                                    "owner":{"idProperty":{
                                                        "name":"id",
                                                        "rawType":"long",
                                                        "field":{
                                                            "name":"id",
                                                            "type":"long",
                                                            "modifiers":2,
                                                            "annotations":[{},{}],
                                                            "synthetic":false,
                                                            "declaredAnnotations":[{},{}],
                                                            "declaringClass":"hello.repository.Video",
                                                            "enumConstant":false,
                                                            "genericType":"long",
                                                            "accessible":true
                                                        },
                                                        "association":false,
                                                            "owner":{"idProperty":{
                                                                "name":"id",
                                                                "rawType":"long",
                                                                "field":{"name":"id",
                                                                    "type":"long",
                                                                    "modifiers":2,
                                                                    "annotations":[{},{}],
                                                                    "synthetic":false,
                                                                    "declaredAnnotations":[{},{}],
                                                                    "declaringClass":"hello.repository.Video",
                                                                    "enumConstant":false,
                                                                    "genericType":"long",
                                                                    "accessible":true
                                                                },
                                                                "association":false,
                                                                "owner":{"idProperty":{
                                                                    "name":"id",
                                                                    "rawType":"long",
                                                                    "field":{
                                                                        "name":"id",
                                                                        "type":"long",
                                                                        "modifiers":2,
                                                                        "annotations":[{},{}],
                                                                        "synthetic":false,
                                                                        "declaredAnnotations":[{},{}],
                                                                        "declaringClass":"hello.repository.Video",
                                                                        "enumConstant":false,
                                                                        "genericType":"long",
                                                                        "accessible":true
                                                                    },
                                                                    "association":false,
                                                                        "owner":{"idProperty":{
                                                                            "name":"id",
                                                                            "rawType":"long",
                                                                            "field":
```

In Eclipse, the output is:

```
2015-08-16 20:21:32.827  WARN 4696 --- [tp1794644129-17] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/favicon.ico] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2015-08-16 20:24:31.773  WARN 4696 --- [tp1794644129-20] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response        : Committed before 500 null
2015-08-16 20:24:31.783  WARN 4696 --- [tp1794644129-20] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Handling of [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException] resulted in Exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.resetBuffer(Response.java:1243)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:544)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.sendServerError(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:313)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.handleHttpMessageNotWritable(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:370)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveException(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:140)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1183)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1020)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:295)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

2015-08-16 20:24:31.807  WARN 4696 --- [tp1794644129-20] o.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler   : 

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentEntityImpl["idProperty"]->org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentPropertyImpl["owner"]->org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentEntityImpl["idProperty"]->org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentPropertyImpl["owner"]->org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentEntityImpl["idProperty"]->org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentPropertyImpl["owner"]->org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentEntityImpl["idProperty"]->org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentPropertyImpl["owner"]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentEntityImpl["idProperty"]->org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentPropertyImpl["owner"]->org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentEntityImpl["idProperty"]->org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentPropertyImpl["owner"]->org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentEntityImpl["idProperty"]->org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentPropertyImpl["owner"]->org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentEntityImpl["idProperty"]->org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentPropertyImpl["owner"])
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:979)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:295)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentEntityImpl["idProperty"]->org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentPropertyImpl["owner"]->org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentEntityImpl["idProperty"]->org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentPropertyImpl["owner"]->org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentEntityImpl["idProperty"]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:238)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:161)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:101)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:185)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceProcessorHandlerMethodReturnValueHandler.handleReturnValue(ResourceProcessorHandlerMethodReturnValueHandler.java:172)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentEntityImpl["idProperty"]->org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentPropertyImpl["owner"]->org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentEntityImpl["idProperty"]->org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentPropertyImpl["owner"]->org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentEntityImpl["idProperty"]->org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentPropertyImpl["owner"]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:653)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:505)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:639)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:505)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:639)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:505)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:639)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:505)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:639)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:505)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:639)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:505)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:639)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:505)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:639)
```

What I did wrong in this project?

This project was based in https://github.com/juleswhite/mobilecloud-15/tree/master/examples/6-VideoServiceWithDataRest, that works but uses Gradle.

Comment: It seems you are having an exception, a recursion in your mapping

Comment: I ran the project and pointed to /video. But I did not get the error. How do I trigger the error?

Comment: In the original project, the error doesn't happens!

Here, with maven, the error always happens.
I run by mvn spring-boot:run

Comment: Please check my answer at  http://stackoverflow.com/a/36704716/1577363

Answer (score 0):

I would like to note that @JsonIgnore does not work for me.  I get this error when ...

(a) I specify the Accept header as "application/x-spring-data-verbose+json" 
and (b) I do this on a very plain JPA Entity with a couple of fields that do not have links to other JPA Entities.

I am using Spring Data 2.4.1.

For everyone's edification, it appears this is an issue with Spring Data. [DATAREST-733](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-733)

Answer (score -1):

I think it's saying that you have a circular relationship somewhere in the entities to be JSONified. I had faced this issue when I had a `User` entity having a `lastModifiedBy` field. When a user was updating himself, `lastModifiedBy` was pointing to the same user object. To fix the issue, I had to annotate the User class with

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "createdBy", "lastModifiedBy" })
```

Comment: Look class https://github.com/murillocg/SpringBootTest/blob/master/src/main/java/hello/repository/Video.java. It's very simple.
The original project at  https://github.com/juleswhite/mobilecloud-15/tree/master/examples/6-VideoServiceWithDataRest, doesn't need this fix and works.

Comment: Yeah, the class does not seem to have anything wrong. But the JSON output you have provided seem to be recursing. Not sure how it is getting generated - it's some HEATOAS probably, I'm not familiar with. But anyway, to me the error seems to be caused by circular recursion only.

Comment: Removing the Object Mapper of Application class, the project ran!